# Publishing Spring Boot JAR from Gradle subproject

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, jar

I am trying to publish a Spring Boot JAR from a subproject, but it fails due to what seems to be eager instantiation within the Gradle Maven Publishing plugin. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        publishSpringBootJar(MavenPublication) {
            artifact project(':application').tasks.getByName('bootJar')
        }
    }
```

While `application` is a Spring Boot subproject that has the Spring Boot plugins applies as usual and DOES define a bootJar task when invoked directly. When I invoke the `publish` task from the parent project I get:

```
Task with name 'bootJar' not found in project ':application'.
```

It seems like the Maven publish plugin tries to eagerly insantiate the publication structure without loading tasks within the individual subprojects. What can I do in this case? Could I indirectly reference the Sprint Boot JAR as an artifact without referring directly to the task that generates it and add a `publish.dependsOn ':application:bootJar'` dependency to the end?

Thank you!

EDIT: The subproject `application` which is in a subdirectory looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please post the main project gradle file too

Comment: Why are you trying to publish a sub-project’s jar? Why not update the application project to publish its own jar?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I want to decouple the publishing from the internal implementation of the subproject. The root (outer) project orchestrates the entire project and copies some files around that the inner subprojects don't know or care about. I prefer the publishing to be another thing that the subprojects don't need to know about.

Comment: What you have tried seems to directly contradict that goal as your publishing relies on knowing about the sub-project’s tasks. Those tasks should be an implementation detail. I think you’d be better reconsidering your approach rather than fighting against Gradle’s configuration model.

Comment: Yup, it looks like there's no good alternatives here, so I ended up embedding the publishing into the subproject. Thank you!